# Required Field Color

Tags: column, spfield

How do you change the colour of either the field or the label of a required field when uploading/editing the properties of a document.

The user says it is hard to see the little * ?

Comment: use jquery to highlight the field control or its label [Refer this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237890/how-do-i-highlight-a-textbox-border-red-when-it-is-required)

Comment: You can do it via CSS, what version are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 STANDARD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite simple, just create a separate CSS file, attach it to the form and apply the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this technique to solve my issue related to required field:
[[SharePoint 2013 - PageLayout required field error message - Change Text / Color](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165035/sharepoint-2013-pagelayout-required-field-error-message-change-text-color][1])