# SharePoint 2013 - PageLayout required field error message - Change Text / Color

Tags: 2013, 2010

I have pagelayout, there are certain required fields.

1. Default error message for required field validation is "You must specify a value for this required field.". Its default color is dark grey, I want to override this color and make it red. Is it possible?
2. Can we change its default text in pagelayout? 
   Note: "ErrorMessage" property is not working for me which is part of BaseControl class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't knew it will be so simple, thanks to my Colleague Zia bhai for helping me in this. Below is the solution:

There is an array being maintained for Page Validators, which contain all the validation controls, you just need to iterate that array and apply the action you want to:

```
var errorMsgControls = Page_Validators;
    for (var i = 0; i < errorMsgControls.length; i++) {
        var ctrl = errorMsgControls[i];
        if (!$(ctrl).hasClass(".ms-formvalidation"))
        {
            $(ctrl).addClass("ms-formvalidation");
        }
    }
```